# <select> tag not working with ThreeJs camera controls

Tags: html, three.js

I've been working on a ThreeJs application where there is a dropdown menu to make selections, which in turn makes changes to the rendered objects.
The problem I'm facing is that when I use the html  tag with camera controls (Trackball or OrbitControls), the select tag doesn't work.

I've written a sample to demonstrate the problem. I couldn't get this to work in a fiddle for some reason.

Js code:

```
var camera, scene, renderer,
sphere, material, mesh;
var controls;
var pointLight;

scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, 300/400, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 300;
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
scene.add( camera );

sphere = new THREE.SphereGeometry(25, 25, 25);
material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xff0000} );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphere, material );
scene.add( mesh );

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( 300, 400 );

document.getElementById("test").appendChild( renderer.domElement );

pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF );
pointLight.position.set (10, 100, 100);
scene.add(pointLight);

render();

function render() {

      renderer.clear();
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
      controls.update();
      renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="scripts/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/TrackballControls.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<div id="test" style="width: 300px; height: 400px; float: right;">
</div>
```

Any idea why this happens and/or what would be a good way around it? All other rendering seems to be working fine.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you instantiate your `TrackballControls` you need set the second argument like so:

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```

Then, of course, your `select` tag needs an event:

```
<select onchange="switchColor( this.value )">
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

function switchColor( value ) {

    mesh.material.color.set( value );

}
```

three.js.r.63